# How can I generate all possible combinations of numbers?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am currently working a python script that would generate all the possible combinations of numbers. I am using the itertools module for this. My problem is: I don´t get doubled numbers in the results. For example: **2**4**5**3**25** or 111222.
Here is my current code:

```
from itertools import permutations

comb = permutations([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0], 6)

f = open("code.txt", "w")

for i in comb:
    nums = str(i)
    cleared = nums.translate({ord(nums): None for nums in ',() '})
    print(cleared)
    f.write(cleared + "\n")
```

Comment: You're looking for [products](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), not permutations.

Comment: This seems like a rather indirect approach. Are you sure you want to create tuples of ints, covert those tuples to `repr`'d strings, and do character substitutions on those strings, and not just, say, iterate `range(10**5, 10**6)`? Do you care about zero prefixes?

Comment: Why 6 numbers only?

Comment: Important question, do you want permutations or combinations?
And if you just want every 6 digit number, just use a range.  Or is the actual set of numbers different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a single line

```py
list(itertools.product(range(10), repeat=6))
```

or based on nigh_anxiety comment

```py
list(range(100000, 1000000))
```

Comment: Missing the final `)`

Comment: Now every list starts with 9. Is there a way to show every combination but including in every order possible?

Comment: @MariusPrakash The list contains tuples, each tuple is unique and is a possible combination of the numbers given, show exactly what you expect